# How can we find a monic polynomial with the smallest degree in left ideal of $\mathrm{Mat}(F[x])$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, modules, ideals

Let $F$ be a finite field, $R=F[x]$ be a polynomial ring and $K = \mathrm{Mat}_n(R)$ be a full matrix ring over $R$. We identify the ring $K$ with the ring $\mathrm{Mat}_n(F)[x]$, for example
$$
\left( \begin{smallmatrix} x&0\\ x^2+1&1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)=
\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 0&0\\ 1&0 \end{smallmatrix} \right)x^2+
\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1&0\\ 0&0 \end{smallmatrix} \right)x+
\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 0&0\\ 1&1 \end{smallmatrix} \right).
$$
 It is known (see, for example [article](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ojm/1200690756))
 that every left ideal $I$ in the ring $K$ is principal left ideal, moreover $I = K\cdot A$ for some triangular matrix $A\in K$.

For given two **monic polynomials** $A(x), B(x)\in K$ I want to **find a monic polynomial $C(x)\in K$ of the smallest degree** such that 
$$
C\in K\cdot A+K\cdot B.
$$

Using the technique of the mentioned [article](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ojm/1200690756) It is quite easily to find a triangular matrix $D$ such that 
$$KA+KB = KD.$$ 
The principal intricacy is to find matrix $C\in KD$ such that the corresponding polynomial from $\mathrm{Mat}_n(F)[x]$ is monic and has the smallest degree.

Maybe it is possible to find the polynomial from $K$ with the smallest degree (not necessarily monic)?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are trying to define the resultant of two non-commutative polynomials. Maybe [this article](https://eudml.org/doc/258360) by Aleksandra Erić will help.